# Doing statistical analysis and charting with large data?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, large-data

I have 4301 lines of data from my science project.  I have to do unorthodox statistical analysis for my results because they are 4-dimensional; I have three independent variables.

With Excel I can do a lot of analysis, even multivariable linear regression, but what I need is a step up:  Multivariable nonlinear regression.

I have R.  Is there a way I can do it with R?

Also, is there a way to generate multiple 3-dimensional graphs with slices of the data automatically?

EDIT:  I've searched with no luck.  Is there *any* way of doing multivariable nonlinear regression automatically?

Comment: Check out the "loess" and "glm" commands in R.  What do you mean by "nonlinear" regression?

Comment: 4000 lines of data is not big.  Try doing analysis on a few million rows!

Answer (score 4):

It's not real clear what you're asking.  Is the following useful?  I knocked it down from 4301 to 430 lines in case your machine is slow.  You can move the little green box around to see how those points fit in all of the other graphs.

```
library(TeachingDemos)

#Build 3 independent variables (for speed reasons, I knocked it down to 430)
x <- rnorm(430)
y <- runif(430)
z <- rnorm(430)

#Build the dependent variable
dep <- 2 + (0.5 * x) + (0.9 * y) + (-0.8 * z)

#Put everything in a data frame
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z, dep=dep)

#Plot it and look at chunks of the data
dra <- tkBrush(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Okay.  I have a table of data 4300 (yeah, it's actually 4300) lines long.  It has 3 independent variables and one dependent variable.  I want to do multivariable linear regression to find how those three IVs affect the DV.  I also want to automatically generate 3-dimensional graphs of each slice of the three IVs (as in leaving one IV constant while using the other two as x and y, and the DV as z).

Answer (score 2):

What sort of nonlinear model do you want?

4300 lines of data is not very large in today's world.  Data sets containing millions of records exist.  Certainly 4300 will be no problem

This link to a work by John Fox may be helpful
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-nonlinear-regression.pdf

it highlights use of the nls function in R, which is part of the nls library

Hope this helps

Comment: (+1) Please note that `nls()` is in the base `stats` package. There exist, however, the [nls2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nls2/index.html) and [nlstools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlstools/index.html) packages on CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

Save your table as a csv file, with one header row that contains the names of your 4 variables.  Save the following code as an R script file in the same directory as your data, and then run it.  Lets say your variables are called X1, X2, X3, and Y, where X1, X2, X3 are your independent variables and Y is your dependent variable.

```
MyData <- read.csv('path/to/MyData.csv')
model <- lm(Y~X1+X2+X3,data=MyData)
predictions <- predict(model)

model
plot(model)
```

Building a linear regression model and diagnosing it is relatively simple in R, even with 4000+ lines of data.  What exactly are you trying to do with this dataset?

You can build a non-linear model using the "loess" or "glm" commands, but specifying and diagnosing such models is more difficult than simple linear models.  Again, if you can be a bit clearer about what exactly you need to do, we can help you more.

Fitting a linear model with 3 dependent variables and 4000 observations isn't exactly unorthodox, and you can do it quickly and easily in R.

Comment: Hey I have `/path/to/results.csv` and `/path/to/command.r`, and it gives me `source("/path/to/command.r")
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'results.csv': No such file or directory`

Comment: How can I fix the above?

Comment: Your question here is unclear. Are you having a problem reading in the results.csv file when you run the script? If so, you might double check that you point the read.csv command at the proper directory(e.g. `read.csv("path/to/results.csv")`). If it's something else with the script, maybe you could tell us what command(s) you're using to run it?

Comment: Open up R and just copy/paste the commands into the console.  Use `MyData <- read.csv('path/to/MyData.csv')`, and then run the rest of the script.

Comment: alternatively, on windows/mac just go source or read csv file.choose() and a window will open up which you can navigate to open the required files.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment to my previous answer "....I also want to automatically generate 3-dimensional graphs of each slice of the three IVs (as in leaving one IV constant while using the other two as x and y, and the DV as z)....."  Try the following (using the same data as above):

```
library(lattice)

#Build 3 independent variables
x <- rnorm(4300)
y <- runif(4300)
z <- rnorm(4300)

#Build the dependent variable
dep <- 2 + (0.5 * x) + (0.9 * y) + (-0.8 * z)

#Put everything in a data frame
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z, dep=dep)

#Break up the x data into 4 chunks of equal counts
df$x4 <- equal.count(df$x, 4)
cloud(dep ~ y + z | x4, data = df,
      zlim = rev(range(df$dep)),
      screen = list(z = 130, x = -65), panel.aspect = 0.75,
      xlab = "y", ylab = "z", zlab = "dep")

#Break up the z data into 2 chunks of equal counts
df$z2 <- equal.count(df$z, 2)
cloud(dep ~ x + y | z2, data = df,
      zlim = rev(range(df$dep)),
      screen = list(z = 160, x = -80), panel.aspect = 0.75,
      xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "dep")
```

The above generates two plots.   Below is the first plot.

[image]